# Possible to use Google Trends to find most popular phrases involving certain word or combination of words?

Tags: google-trends

I'm wondering if it's possible to use Google Trends or some other app to figure out the most commonly search phrases that involve a certain word.

Let say I want to find phrases that are above three words that contain the word gun or firearm.  Once popular search might be "guns don't kill people."  Is there any way to get a list of the most popular phrases that contain certain words?